# Windows 7 Blue Screen After Power Cut During Update

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-update

My windows was updating displaying the "Configuring Windows Update" and suddnly there was a power cut so pc shutdown, after that whenever i tried to boot it and it will pass the windows 7 logo screen then the mouse appears then i get the lovely BSOD (Blue Screen of Death).

I want to note that i have windows 8 installed so if there is anyway i can fix it from there please mention it.

Here is what i tried and didn't work of course:

1. 1-Safe Mode, same problem
2. 2-Last Good Configuration when you press F8
3. 3-I entered the Repair Windows, after that i tried to use the
   Startup Repair option, it detected an error but when it tried to fix
   it everything crashes and it tells that you problem can't be fixed.

Is there any solutions left that maybe i can try ? If not, can't i maybe fix it by installing part of windows or maybe copy some files

Does using Repair without DVD similar if tried with DVD ?

Comment: Use a Restoration Point;  Boot to a `Windows 8` and use `WinRE` to do so.

Comment: Sadly i had the Windows Restore disabled from the begging

Comment: You are likely out of luck in that case.  Its clear you have a corrupt system file, although without specifics about the BSOD, its hard to say.

Comment: which STOP code do you see?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely try a repair using the install disk.  It makes a difference.

If you can, roll back to the last good system restore.

Comment: Windows Restore was disabled, i will try you suggestion with the disk though

Comment: It didn't work, produced the same error